# How to return volley jsonobject from class to activity in android

Tags: android, android-volley, json

I am trying volley library response, here i am getting response as per my expectation but am not am able to return the jsonobject to my activity, i am planning to write a single method that will give response all over the application in android, ok i am coming to the point now,

I have a class called Util.java, in this class i have return jsonobject like below

```
public JSONObject fetchResponse() {

    try {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json = createStuff();

        URL = "my url here" + json.toString();

        final JsonObjectRequest volleyRes = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //fetchRes = result(response);
                    //fetchRes = new JSONObject();
                    //fetchRes = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    Log.w("UTIL res 61 ", fetchRes.toString());
                    // result(fetchRes);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w("UTILrespon error ", "" + e);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
                Log.w("UTIL res error ", "" + e);
            }
        });

        volleyRes.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 2, 2));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(volleyRes);
        Log.w("UTIL res 83 ", fetchRes.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("UTIL Error ", "" + e);
    }
    return fetchRes;

}
```

Here **fetchRes** is an jsonobject which i declared outside of this method

now my problem is, when i am running my app, i can get the response from this method

```
     @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {

            //  fetchRes = result(response);
            //   fetchRes = new JSONObject();
            fetchRes = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            Log.w("UTIL res 61 ", response.toString());
            // result(fetchRes);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.w("UTILrespon error ", "" + e);
        }

    }
```

once i get the response i can't store in another jsonobject and can't return to my MainActivity.java in android.. so please anyone help me to come out of this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

create classes of json object and use Gson library. It directly converts json string to objects.

Example :-

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyBean myBean;
myBean = gson.fromJson(response.toString,MyBeans.class);
```

Comment: ok but i am using different different bean classes so this idea will not work in app, if i can return jsonobject without null that's enough to me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Define an interface
interface FetResponseListener {
    void onFetchResponse(JSONObject response);
}
```

Pass this interface as parameter to `fetchResponse`

```
public void fetchResponse(FetResponseListener listener) {
    ....

   @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            listener.onFetchResponse(response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("UTILrespon error ", "" + e);
        }
    } 
}
```

Implement `FetResponseListener` where you call `fetchResponse`

```
fetchResponse(new FetResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFetchResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // use json response
    }
});
```

Or just use [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)